# ReactNative - Objects are not valid as React child

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am getting this error -

"Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof , type, key, ref, props, _owner, _store}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead"

This is specifically running the Android Emulator.

Here's my code:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      userEmail: null
    }
    //this.authCheck = this.authCheck.bind(this)
    //this.toggleLogin = this.toggleLogin.bind(this)
    this.signIn = this.signIn.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.authListener()
  }

  authListener() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        console.log(user.email)
        this.setState({userEmail: user.email})

      } else {
        console.log('no user signed in')
        this.setState({userEmail: null})
      }
      })
  }

  signIn(email, password) {
    //console.log(email, password)
    //console.log(this.state.userEmail)
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log(errorCode, errorMessage)
        // ...
      })
  }

  signUp(email, password) {
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      console.log(errorCode, errorMessage)
      // ...
    })
  }

  logOut() {
    firebase.auth().signOut()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.state.userEmail ? <ItWorked logOut={this.logOut}/> : <SignUp signIn={this.signIn} signUp={this.signUp} toggleLogin={this.toggleLogin}/>}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's difficult to say what might be wrong without seeing how `ItWorked` and `SignUp` are implemented, since that's all that is rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is exactly as you wrote it, then `ItWorked` and `SignUp` should be `undefined`, which would give you an error if you try to use them in the `render` method.

If you did `import` those two components, then you might not be importing and exporting them correctly. If this is the case, you might have done something like:

```
// App.js

// Note that this import expects SignUp to be the default export of SignUp.js
import SignUp from './components/SignUp.js' 

export default class App extends Component {
 ...


// SignUp.js

// Note that this is a named export of SignUp
export function SignUp() {
  return <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
}
```

To solve this, either export `SignUp` as the default:

```
// SignUp.js

export default function SignUp() {
  return <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
}
```

OR import SignUp as a named import:

```
// App.js

import { SignUp } from './components/SignUp.js'
...
```

But not both.

---

Another possible issue is that the rendered components (
`ItWorked` and `SignUp`) are wrapped in higher order components (like react-redux's `connect`), but the exporting file does not actually *call* the HOC.

I suspect you might find that one (or both) of those files does something like this:

```
// SignUp.js

function SignUp(props) {
  return <div>Lorum Ipsum</div>
}

// Possible current export
export default connect(mapStateToProps)

// "Correct" export
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SignUp)
```

Either way, the problem probably lies in the `SignUp` and `ItWorks` components or how they are imported by `App`, and it would help to get a bit more context into those components.

Comment: So at the top of my app.js file, I do have these:


import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase'
import SignUp from './components/auth/signup'
import ItWorked from './components/auth/itworked'

Comment: How did you export `SignUp` and `ItWorked`? These would appear as lines starting with `export ...` in `./components/auth/signup` and `./components/auth/itworked`